# Google Cloud SDK Authentication

Tags: sdk, google-cloud-platform

After installing Google Cloud SDK, When i run

gcloud auth login

I get an error message :

```
Your browser has been opened to visit:
 https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope= .... <whole link>

GConf Error: Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.)
GConf Error: Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.)
Error showing url: Operation not supported
```

What could cause this problem and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

I tried installing GConf again but it did not help.

The problem was I had two accounts on chrome to be signed in, and the error was caused as while opening the authentication link. it did not get the required response.

I simply copied the authentication link https://accounts.google.com/o/... from the command line window and pasted it in browser window, which gave me an option to sign in from my desired account. I signed in and I was successfully authenticated.